# MySQL Workbench の dashboard において、 table open cache の efficiency とは?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

以下は、自分の手元の MySQL Workbench, dashboard の画面です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画面において、真ん中の、 「Table Open Cache」 の Efficiency とは何を表しますか?

これは、 Efficiency ということで、 100% に近ければ問題ないのでしょうか。

また逆に、これがわりと小さいときがあるような気もしていますが、その場合は何か問題があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のページなどをみていて、以下の結論に至りました。 https://qiita.com/kakuka4430/items/72dc5366c9cdf65e78e9

- Table Open Cache とは、 MySQL プロセスが開いておける(file を open しておける)テーブルの数

  - 通常、単一のプロセスが開くことができるファイルの数は OS によって規定されているので、 MySQL でもその個数をサーバーパラメータとして指定ができる
- この上限に達した上で新たにテーブルファイルを開こうとする場合、おそらく LRU なファイルデスクリプタを閉じる
- cache efficiency なので、多分このファイルデスクリプタキャッシュのヒット率が、 `Table Open Cache` の Efficiency として表示されている。